# Spark scala udf error for if else

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, udf

I am trying to define udf with the function getTIme for spark scala udf but i am getting the error as `error: illegal start of declaration`. What might be error in the syntax and retutrn the date  and also if there is parse exception instead of returing the null, send the some string as *error*

```
def getTime=udf((x:String) : java.sql.Timestamp => {
 if (x.toString() == "")  return null  
else { val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"); 
val d = format.parse(x.toString());
val t = new Timestamp(d.getTime()); return t  
}})
```

Thank you!

Comment: try null.asInstanceOf[Timestamp] in if condition

Comment: I think that null.asInstanceOf[Timestamp]  is for the error message during parse date is null but what is the error "error: illegal start of declaration"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type for the udf is derived and should not be specified. Change the first line of code to:

```
def getTime=udf((x:String) => {
// your code
}
```

This should get rid of the error.

The following is a fully working code written in functional style and making use of Scala constructs:

```
val data: Seq[String] = Seq("", null, "2017-01-15 10:18:30")
val ds = spark.createDataset(data).as[String]

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.sql.Timestamp

val fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
// ********HERE  is the udf completely re-written: **********
val f = udf((input: String) => {
  Option(input).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(str => new Timestamp(fmt.parse(str).getTime)).orNull
})

val ds2 = ds.withColumn("parsedTimestamp", f($"value"))
```

The following is output:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
|              value|     parsedTimestamp|
+-------------------+--------------------+
|                   |                null|
|               null|                null|
|2017-01-15 10:18:30|2017-01-15 10:18:...|
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Scala datatypes, not Java datatypes. It would go like this:

```
def getTime(x: String): Timestamp = {
//your code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in this way :

```
  def getTimeFunction(timeAsString: String): java.sql.Timestamp = {
  if (timeAsString.isEmpty)
    null
  else {
    val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss")
    val date = format.parse(timeAsString.toString())
    val time = new Timestamp(date.getTime())
    time
  }
}
val getTimeUdf = udf(getTimeFunction _)
```

Then use this **getTimeUdf** accordingly. !

Comment: Where is the String input is given to the udf(getTimeFunction _) here.